# How to change kernel settings, shared memory configuration?

Tags: macos, postgresql, kernel

I'm trying to install PostgreSQL and I need to allow for more shared memory configuration. Following the PostgreSQL documentation here:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/kernel-resources.html

I just need to find a file called `/etc/sysctl.conf`, but I'm having a hard time.

But I guess you could say I'm new with computers, and I have no idea how to locate this file on my Mac, and google isn't helping. Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you read this documentation? It says "In OS X 10.3.9 and later, instead of editing /etc/rc you may **create** a file named /etc/sysctl.conf .."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you will need to start a terminal to do this press Cmd + Space to start a spotlight search then enter term and terminal will be one of the top mos matches. Click it to start it.

In the terminal you will have to start an editor using the root account and open the file. You do this by typing:

```
sudo vi /etc/sysctl.conf
```

It will ask for your password before elevating to the root account. Then the editor vi will open the specified file or create a new file if it doesn't already exist. Now vi is a bit hard to use for people who do not know here so here is a very quick intro. Press i once to enter edit mode. Now you can enter the required lines as in most editors.

When you are ready to save press Escape to leave edit mode. Then type (including the colon) :wq (w is for write q is for quit) if you don't want exit without saving your changes do escape followed by :q! (q for quit, ! force discarding changes)

Comment: thanks! a friend helped me with this yesterday already, but he told me to do exactly this. thanks again!